# What is the python standards by which a string is parsed to float?

Tags: python, floating-point

For relatively simple floats, the numerical precision is sufficient to represent them exactly. For example, 17.5 is equal to 17.5

For more complicated floats, such as

```
17.4999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546874 = 17.499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375
17.4999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 = 17.5
```

Using as_integer_ratio() on the first number above, one obtains `(4925812092436479, 281474976710656)` and since `(4925812092436479*2+1)/(2*281474976710656)` equals the second number above, it becomes evident that the partition between >=17.5 and <17.5 is 1/(2*281474976710656).

Do the python standards guarantee a particular float will be "binned" into a particular bin above, or is it implementation dependent? If there is a guarantee, how is it decided?

For the above I used, python 3.5.6, but I am interested in the general answer for python 3.x if it exists.

Comment: I guess it depends on which version of strtod() the C compiler uses with which the Python runtime was compiled. There can be slight differences.

Comment: There are no official guarantees, but for CPython it's extremely likely that you're using IEEE 754 binary64 floating-point, and that numeric literals in code are converted to the nearest exactly representable floating-point number, with ties being rounded to the value with even last bit. If that's not happening on a mainstream platform, I'd consider that a bug that's worth reporting to bugs.python.org. Happily, the values you show follow this rule. The second value that you give is precisely halfway between two exactly representable values, so by the round-ties-to-even rule it rounds up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For relatively simple floats, the numerical precision is sufficient to represent them exactly

Not really. Yes, *17.5* can be represented exactly because it is a multiple of a power of two (a multiple of 2<sup>-1</sup>, to be exact). But even very simple floats like *0.1* cannot be represented exactly. There it depends on the text to float conversion routine to get a representation that is as close as possible.

The conversion is done by the runtime (or the C or Java runtime of the compiler, for literals), which uses the C or Java functions (like C's *strtod()*) to do this (Java implements the code of David Gay's *strtod()*, but in Java language).

Not every implementation of *strtod()*, i.e. not every C/Java compiler uses the same methodology to convert, so there may be slight, usually insignificant differences in **some of the results**.

---

*FWIW, the website [Exploring Binary](https://www.exploringbinary.com/topics/)  (no affiliation, I'm just a big fan) has many articles on this subject. It is obviously not as simple as expected.*

Comment: For CPython, on almost all machines, the conversion is _not_ done by the C runtime: Python has it's own implementation of `strtod` and `dtoa`, based on David Gay's code, and it uses those.

Comment: @Mark: "David Gay's code is usually used". The other code (Burger/Dybvig, etc.) is, AFAIK, round-robin code, i.e. the mininal output that, if parsed again, reproduces the same value. But indeed, many languages use Gay's code, including Java, C, C++ and Python.

Comment: The code we're using is also round-robin code. Gay's code is, I believe, based on the algorithms you mention. The whole point of using Gay's code was to achieve round-tripping from float to string and back to float (and to get the minimal-length string that rounds to the correct float).

Comment: AFAIK, Gay's code only cares about correct rounding, and roundtripping **output** is not always correctly rounded. See the example with the correct value 1.100...01 where the shorter roundtripping output would be 1.1.

Comment: I'm not sure which exact example you're referring to. Gay's `dtoa` implementation has various modes, including correct rounding to a given number of places after (or before) the point, correct rounding to a given number of significant digits, and shortest string that will round back to the given value. Python uses the last mode for its `repr`, and the first two modes for `%f` and `%e` or `%g`-style float formatting. I'm somewhat familiar with this, since I implemented Python's adaptation of `dtoa.c` (discovering several dtoa.c bugs in the process) and wrote extensive tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

> For relatively simple floats, the numerical precision is sufficient to represent them exactly.

No, even simple decimals don't necessarily have an exact IEEE-754 representation:

```py
>>> format(0.1, '.20f')
'0.10000000000000000555'
>>> format(0.2, '.20f')
'0.20000000000000001110'
>>> format(0.3, '.20f')
'0.29999999999999998890'
>>> format(0.1 + 0.2, '.20f')
'0.30000000000000004441'
```

*Powers of 2* (x.0, x.5, x.25, x.125, …) are exactly representable, modulo precision issues.

> Do the python standards guarantee a particular float will be "binned" into a particular bin above, or is it implementation dependent?

Pretty sure Python simply delegates to the underlying system, so it's mostly hardware-dependent. If you want guarantees, use `decimal`. IIRC the native (C) implementation was merged in 3.3, and the performance impact of using decimals has thus become much, much lower than it was in Python 2.

Comment: CPython at least does not simply delegate to the underlying system. The CPython codebase includes a file dtoa.c, based on David Gay's code, that implements conversions between float and string on most machines. (Disclaimer: non IEEE 754 machines can't use this code, but those are extremely rare.)

Comment: String formatting is not the subject of the question, just a way to demonstrate the precision issue inherent to IEEE 754 floats.

Comment: Sure, but the statement "Pretty sure Python simply delegates to the underlying system, so it's mostly hardware-dependent." is misleading. It doesn't, and it isn't, at least for CPython.

Comment: That statement is contextual, and the context is the question's subject and even more so the part of the question quoted before that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Python floats are [IEEE-754 doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double_precision).

Comment: [Python leaves floating-point to the underlying platform](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types): “You are at the mercy of the underlying machine architecture (and C or Java implementation) for the accepted range and handling of overflow.” It is commonly something close to IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point, but this is not guaranteed by Python, and it is not always fully compliant with IEEE 754.

Comment: @Eric: that is more or less what I wrote. I forgot to mention the Java implementations, though.